# Using perl to find median, mode, Standard deviation?

Tags: perl, statistics

I have an array of numbers. What is the easiest way to calculate the Median, Mode, and Std Dev for the data set?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# stdev - figure N, min, max, median, mode, mean, & std deviation
#
# pull out all the real numbers in the input
# stream and run standard calculations on them.
# they may be intermixed with other test, need
# not be on the same or different lines, and 
# can be in scientific notion (avagadro=6.02e23).
# they also admit a leading + or -.
#
# Tom Christiansen
# tchrist@perl.com

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw< min max >;

sub by_number {
    if ($a < $b){ -1 } elsif ($a > $b) { 1 } else { 0 }
}


#
my $number_rx = qr{

  # leading sign, positive or negative
    (?: [+-] ? )

  # mantissa
    (?= [0123456789.] )
    (?: 
        # "N" or "N." or "N.N"
        (?:
            (?: [0123456789] +     )
            (?:
                (?: [.] )
                (?: [0123456789] * )
            ) ?
      |
        # ".N", no leading digits
            (?:
                (?: [.] )
                (?: [0123456789] + )
            ) 
        )
    )

  # abscissa
    (?:
        (?: [Ee] )
        (?:
            (?: [+-] ? )
            (?: [0123456789] + )
        )
        |
    )
}x;

my $n = 0;
my $sum = 0;
my @values = ();

my %seen = ();

while (<>) {
    while (/($number_rx)/g) {
        $n++;
        my $num = 0 + $1;  # 0+ is so numbers in alternate form count as same
        $sum += $num;
        push @values, $num;
        $seen{$num}++;
    } 
} 

die "no values" if $n == 0;

my $mean = $sum / $n;

my $sqsum = 0;
for (@values) {
    $sqsum += ( $_ ** 2 );
} 
$sqsum /= $n;
$sqsum -= ( $mean ** 2 );
my $stdev = sqrt($sqsum);

my $max_seen_count = max values %seen;
my @modes = grep { $seen{$_} == $max_seen_count } keys %seen;

my $mode = @modes == 1 
            ? $modes[0] 
            : "(" . join(", ", @modes) . ")";
$mode .= ' @ ' . $max_seen_count;

my $median;
my $mid = int @values/2;
my @sorted_values = sort by_number @values;
if (@values % 2) {
    $median = $sorted_values[ $mid ];
} else {
    $median = ($sorted_values[$mid-1] + $sorted_values[$mid])/2;
} 

my $min = min @values;
my $max = max @values;

printf "n is %d, min is %g, max is %g\n", $n, $min, $max;
printf "mode is %s, median is %g, mean is %g, stdev is %g\n", 
    $mode, $median, $mean, $stdev;
```

Comment: Is this better than `sub by_number { return $a <=> $b }`, for some definition of "better"?

Comment: What's wrong with `my @sorted_values = sort {$a <=> $b} @values;`?

Comment: @hepcat72 That's a good question, really. I no longer recall why I did that.

Comment: Is there any value in calling min and max functions if you've just sorted the data?

Answer (score 30):

- [`Statistics::Basic::Mean`](http://p3rl.org/Statistics::Basic::Mean)
- [`Statistics::Basic::Median`](http://p3rl.org/Statistics::Basic::Median)
- [`Statistics::Basic::Mode`](http://p3rl.org/Statistics::Basic::Mode)
- [`Statistics::Basic::StdDev`](http://p3rl.org/Statistics::Basic::StdDev)

Comment: Why is there no `Statistics::Basic::Max` or `Statistics::Basic::Min` in that module?

Comment: Because they're in List::Util, which is in Core.

Answer (score 15):

Depending on how in depth you need to go, erickb's answer may work. However for numerical functionality in Perl there is [PDL](http://pdl.perl.org). You would create a piddle (the object containing your data) using the [`pdl`](http://pdl.perl.org/?docs=Core&title=PDL::Core#pdl) function. From there you can use the operations on [this page](http://pdl.perl.org/?docs=Ufunc&title=PDL::Ufunc) to do the statistics you need.

Edit: Looking around I found two function calls that do EXACTLY what you need. [`statsover`](http://pdl.perl.org/PDLdocs/Primitive.html#statsover) gives statistics on one dimension of a piddle, while `stats` does the same over the whole piddle.

```
my $piddle = pdl @data;
my ($mean,$prms,$median,$min,$max,$adev,$rms) = statsover $piddle;
```

Comment: I actually hadn't heard of PDL before, I guess since most of what I've done has been sysadmin tools development and whatnot.  This is actually really cool, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @BadFileMagic, I was really bummed after seeing a talk on NumPy/SciPy thinking that this finally meant I had to leave Perl for Python. Then I found PDL. All good.

Comment: Never heard of this before. Looks incredible!