# Statistics of a number stream

Tags: python, perl, bash

I have a file with several lines, each containing some 30,000 integers. I'm interested in computing various statistical quantities such as mean/media/variance/etc., per line.

For example, given a file whose contents are

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 8 9 0 10 11 12
```

I would like an output similar to

```
(std = 1.4142135623730951, mean = 3.0, median = 3.0)
(std = 3.7416573867739413, mean = 8.0, median = 9.0)
```

What are my options apart from writing the thing myself (acquiring Happiness Through Numerics)  ? Are there any one-liners for this?

A bash/python/perl/etc. solution is preferred, as is simplicity.

Comment: Do you have numpy?  If so, it should be pretty easy ...

Comment: @simbabque Have a look at my questions without an accept; what would you accept if you were me?

Comment: Sorry, I just looked at how many questions there are, not at the number of replies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite a 1-liner, but quite simple (provided you've installed numpy).

```
import numpy as np
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        a=np.array(line.split(),dtype=int)
        print(a.std(),a.mean(),np.median(a))  #standard-deviation, mean, median
```

Comment: Brilliant. 5-liner is the same as 1-liner.

Comment: It's a 6 liner if you want to get the input filename from the commandline as then you need to `import sys` ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you install the [`Statistics::Basic`](https://metacpan.org/module/Statistics%3a%3aBasic) module, it looks like this in Perl. Most of the command is the format string!

```
perl -MStatistics::Basic=:all -lane 'printf "(std = %.16f, mean = %.1f, median = %.1f)\n",stddev(@F),mean(@F),median(@F)' datafile
```

**output**

```
(std = 1.4142135623730951, mean = 3.0, median = 3.0)
(std = 3.7416573867739413, mean = 8.0, median = 9.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119034/using-perl-to-find-median-mode-standard-deviation) directly addresses your question in Perl.  I think it is somewhat doubtful you'll get this down to a one-liner.

Here's an example using [PDL](http://pdl.perl.org/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use PDL;

open my $FILE, '<', './numbers.txt';

my @numbers = <$FILE>;

foreach my $number_set ( @numbers ) {
    my $piddle = pdl $number_set;
    my ($mean,$prms,$median,$min,$max,$adev,$rms) = statsover $piddle;
    printf "(std = %f, mean = %3.1f, median = %3.1f)\n", $rms, $mean, $median;
}
```

Numbers.txt contains:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 8 9 0 10 11 12
```

---

**Edit**

As a one-line shell command this looks like

```
perl -MPDL -lne 'printf "(std = %7\$.16f, mean = %1\$.1f, median = %3\$.1f)\n", statsover pdl $_' numbers.txt
```

Comment: I've added a one-line equivalent to your answer. By the way the standard deviation is `$rms` not `$adev`. I've fixed that too. Hope that's OK

Comment: @Borodin - That's totally fine, Thank you!